# Sum function not working correctly with dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, sum

I am using a large excel file with four columns, but I only require two: Date and HPCP. The goal of this program is to convert the dates to date objects, remove duplicate dates, and then sum the HPCP of the duplicates. I feel like this code should work, however, the output is very wrong. The code successfully converts the dates to date objects, removes duplicates, but does not sum correctly. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Link to excel file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P5-k9Zyz8iFwx6Y-9yhnRozGGSvqpXLz

Example some rows from the excel file:

```
      STATION           STATION_NAME         DATE        HPCP
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000101 01:00  0
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000104 15:00  0
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000104 16:00  0.01
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000104 17:00  0.03
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000104 18:00  0.04
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000104 19:00  0.12
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000104 20:00  0.17
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000104 21:00  0.13
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000104 22:00  0.04
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000104 23:00  0.09
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000105 00:00  0.07
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000105 01:00  0
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000109 21:00  0.01
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000109 22:00  0
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000110 00:00  0.01
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000110 13:00  0.15
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000110 14:00  0.29
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000110 15:00  0.24
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000110 16:00  0.15
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000110 17:00  0.01
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000113 08:00  0
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000113 09:00  0.01
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000113 10:00  0.02
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000113 15:00  0.01
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000113 16:00  0.01
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000113 17:00  0
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000120 07:00  0
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000120 08:00  0
COOP:305801 NY CITY  CENTRAL PARK NY US  20000120 09:00  0
```

Code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])
data = data[['DATE','HPCP']]

data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE'])

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print index
    data.loc[index,'DATE'] = data.loc[index,'DATE'].date()

data = data.groupby(['DATE'],as_index=False).sum()

print data
```

Output:

```
        DATE      HPCP
0    2000-01-01  11999.88
1    2000-01-03      0.00
2    2000-01-04   1002.97
3    2000-01-05      1.25
4    2000-01-09   1000.01
5    2000-01-10      4.72
6    2000-01-11      0.00
7    2000-01-13      0.17
8    2000-01-16      0.00
9    2000-01-20   1000.11
10   2000-01-21      0.12
        ...       ...
2871 2013-12-17      0.66
2872 2013-12-21      0.01
2873 2013-12-22      0.04
2874 2013-12-23      2.06
2875 2013-12-24      0.00
2876 2013-12-26      0.00
2877 2013-12-29      4.90
2878 2013-12-30      0.00
2879 2013-12-31      0.00
2880 2014-01-01   3999.96
```

Comment: Why do you think it isn't right?

Comment: all the values for HPCP are very small (all are under 1 in the excel file). The values given in the output after using the sum function are just wrong.

Comment: I can neither confirm nor deny that without your data (and I certainly need more than 1 row). You have only posted your code and output, both of which seem right to me. What would you have me do now?

Comment: Pick a date that seems wrong to you (say, `2014-01-01`), filter out only those rows into a list, then print out the list of HPCP values and their final sum. That'll help you either work out the issue in your code's logic or in your expectations.

Comment: I just uploaded some more rows of the data. If you look at the data I posted you can see that the output is not what it should be.

Comment: No, we can't, not without the complete dataset. If this were your entire dataset, then sure, it'd be wrong... but if the dataset is a million rows long, then `0.17 + 0.22 + a hundred thousand other values` could easily add up to the values you're seeing. Try computing these summations using some other method, then if the answers come out differently, show us that code and its outputs and we can work from there. E.g., try `sample = data[data['DATE'] == '2014-01-01']; print(len(sample)); print(sum(sample))`

Comment: Please upload a sample of rows that actually reproduces your error with your code when run on just that sample.

Comment: You don't need the whole dataset. I couldn't even put it in here if I wanted to. The whole dataset is 70,000 rows. Also, the data is all in chronological order so it doesn't matter if it is a million rows long, all the duplicate dates occur right after each other and you can compare what I have posted to the output without needing the whole file. Also, there is no error, it just produces incorrect numbers.

Comment: We don't need the whole dataset.  We need something that shows the sort of result you're seeing, since the data you're giving here doesn't give the result you show.  (And what are "incorrect numbers" if not an error?)

Comment: If you refuse to give us a reproducible example, I'd suggest you use `sort_values` to see where the bad values are in your `HPCP` column.

Comment: By looking at the example data I supplied and reading the introduction I wrote you can see that the output is incorrect...There are also no bad values. These are the first 60 or so values of HPCP:                                                                                                  
0
0
0.01
0.03
0.04
0.12
0.17
0.13
0.04
0.09
0.07
0
0.01
0
0.01
0.15
0.29
0.24
0.15
0.01
0
0.01
0.02
0.01
0.01
0
0
0
0
0.02
0.01
0.02
0.02
0
0.02
0.01
0.01
0.01
0
0
0
0
0.05
0.12
0.12
0.14
0.03
0.03
0.01
0
0.03
0.02
0
0.05
0.02
0.03
0.01
0
0.03

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve about how to produce the sort of example that will help us help you. If we can't duplicate your problem, we can't fix it.

Comment: Using your exact post and avoiding the `for` loop, I cannot reproduce your issue. Run [this script](https://pastebin.com/U7C0tM35) in a empty Python environment and see for yourself.

Comment: I provided a link to the entire dataset

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong, those large values are correct. I imported your data file into Excel, created a pivot table using just the data as each row and the sum of HPCP as the value, and here are the first few results:

```
Row Labels  Sum of HPCP
1/1/2000    11999.88
1/3/2000    0
1/4/2000    1002.97
1/5/2000    1.25
1/9/2000    1000.01
...
```

The good news is that your code is fine.

To cap off the long discussion in the comments to your question, I'll just say that you need to distinguish "surprising" from "wrong". These results are "surprising" given the generally small values in the HPCP column, but they're not "wrong". Maybe you want a different metric (mean? max?) or you want to do some pre-filtering, but for the data you've given and the description of what you want to do, your code and its results are correct, even if the output values are unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous lines in the .csv file you link to with `HPCP` of 999.99.  Your sum is working correctly for this data.